# Display a alert message on Lightning Component (Pop up Modal)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error-messages, alert

In my pop up search when my select returns zero records, I want to show the alert message and  if its searching for existing records I want show the different alert message too. I added the error condition in Controller method but its not working, please help.

````
**Lightning Component**

<div  onkeyup="{!c.handleKeyUp}">
                   <lightning:input aura:id="enter-search" name="enter-search"  label="Search for Existing Customer Records" type="search" value="{!v.queryterm}"
                                    placeholder ="Search using First Name or Last Name or EmailAddress!" isLoading="{!v.issearching}"/>
               </div>

**Controller**

   handleKeyUp: function (component, event, helper) {
       if (event.which == 13){
           component.set('v.issearching', true);
           setTimeout(function() {
               var queryTerm = component.find('enter-search').get('v.value');
               helper.getCustomerRecords(component,queryTerm); 
               component.set('v.issearching', false);
           }, 1000);
       } else if(state == "ERROR"){
                       var errors = response.getError();                       
                           component.set("v.showErrors",true);
                           component.set("v.errorMessage",errors[0].message);
                          
                   }
   }

**Helper**

getCustomerRecords : function(component, queryTerm) {
       var action = component.get("c.searchCustomer");
       action.setParams({
           "searchstring": queryTerm
       });
       var selected = [];
       var records = component.get("v.selectedCustomerData");
       records.forEach(function(record){
           selected.push(record.Id);
       });
       action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
           var state = response.getState();
           if (state === "SUCCESS") {
               var returnrecords = response.getReturnValue();
               var mergedrecords = [];
               returnrecords.forEach(function(returnrecord){
                   if(!selected.includes(returnrecord.Id)){
                       mergedrecords.push(returnrecord);   
                   }
               });
               mergedrecords = mergedrecords.concat(records);
               component.set("v.customerData",mergedrecords);
               component.set("v.selectedCustomerKey",selected);
           }
           else {
               console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
           }
       });
       $A.enqueueAction(action);
   }```
````

Comment: what is not working ? can you provide debugging details ? any error messages? "not working" is not helpful for us to provide any help. Please update your post accordingly

Comment: I am not getting any alert message but I am trying to show alert in my pop up.

Comment: Basically I am not sure how to get alert message when my search result is zero or when its searching for existing record.